# convert C# code to assembly

Tags: c#, dll, assembly, converters

I have this quite complicated algorithm written in C# and what I need now is to write the same thing in Assembler, I know the basics, but I would really appreciate some clues about app's structure and how to handle matrix in asm. (It's going to be .dll I assume)

Here is the algorithm:
http://pastebin.com/iGKcK1rF

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you pasted is not C

Comment: Already retagged as C#

Comment: I would rewrite it in C, ask the compiler to optimize like crazy (loop unrolling, etc), then profile, and try optimize the slow bits in ASM.

Comment: It needs to be asm definitely, with no use of C unfortunately. Also the problem is it can't be compiled (it's a class only, dependent on another class - what I need is to replace this class Matrix with some other mechanisms of handling data. I don't need it to be strictly converted to ASM, I need it to do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to use your C compiler to generate assembly code from your C code.  Then you could study this generated code and improve it.  If you are using `gcc` compiler, launch is with `-S` option to generate assembly code.  If you are using compiler from MS Visual Studio named `cl`, pass `/Fa` option to it.

Comment: The problem is it can't be compiled, it's a class only, dependent on another class - what I need is to replace this class Matrix with some other mechanisms of handling data. I don't need it to be strictly converted to ASM, I need it to do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mikhail's answer above:

1. Profile before you optimize! Look up "gprof". Here's a useful link:
   http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC2
2. Using the results of profiling, partition your code into compute-intensive inner loops and "outer code".
3. Convert the inner loops into asm (using Mikhail's suggestion, or some other method) and then call them from your program.

Comment: I'd try using inline assembler for the critical code - it's somewhat easier than writing a separate ASM module.

Comment: and my mistake, it's C# code, but I guess it should make no difference hum ;>

Comment: The problem is it can't be compiled (it's a class only, dependent on another class - what I need is to replace this class Matrix with some other mechanisms of handling data. I don't need it to be strictly converted to ASM, I need it to do the same job.